# Facebook custom share button not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-share

I am developing an Android app. I am integrating Facebook share feature to my app. But my Facebook share code is not working.  I am sharing a photo with some text content. Before sharing I have to convert URL to bitmap.

I am converting URL to bitmap in asynchronous task because it throws error it I do not use it. But when I click share button, it is doing nothing.

This is my Facebook share function that is fired when share button is clicked

```
 public void btnShareClick(View v)
    {
        if(facebookShareImageUrl!=null && facebookShareImageUrl.isEmpty()==false)
        {
            new AsyncTask<String,String,Bitmap>(){
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                }

                @Override
                protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                    return CommonHelper.ConvertUrlToBitmap(facebookShareImageUrl);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                    super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
                    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                            .setBitmap(bitmap)
                            .build();
                    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                            .addPhoto(photo)
                            .build();
                    ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(ItemActivity.this);
                    shareDialog.show(ItemActivity.this, content);
                }
            }.execute(null,null,null);
        }

    }
```

This is my content provider in manifest

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider123435456656"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true" />
```

I set other credentials correctly because my Facebook login is working. Why is this not working?

I tried testing this code as well removing async task. But not just working, UI does not change at all even 1 px.

```
 private void sharePhotoToFacebook(){
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(image)
            .setCaption("Give me my codez or I will ... you know, do that thing you don't like!")
            .build();

    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo)
            .build();

    ShareApi.share(content, null);

}
```

Comment: you are executing AsyncTask with null parameters, what do you expect ?

Comment: But my async task is working